# Django Upgrade from 1.11 to 2.2.1 Problem with URLs and Paths

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-2.2

Today I decided to upgrade my project from Django 1.11 to 2.2.1.  I've been working through various issues with my project, and I'm fighting through them.  However, I spent most of tonight trying to get the URLs to work and they won't cooperate.  Long story short, I have multiple app in my project and each app has a URL with it's own namespace.  In Django 1.11 this is working fine.  However, when I try to port the logic over to Django 2.2.1, I keep getting an error saying that I have a circular import somewhere probably.

Here is a snippit of what works just fine in Django 1.11.......

My Main Project...In Django 1.11

```
url(r'^Main/',include('AppA.urls',namespace="AppA")),
```

But when I try to do this in Django 2.2.1.....

I realize that URLs were replaced by paths...

```
path('', include('AppA.urls')),
```

But when I try to start my application it says....

```
your project does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid p
atterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I can't seem to figure out how to create the namespace that is working in django 1.11 so that I can properly reference my urls in my templates.

I've been staring at this most of the evening and that might be why I'm not seeing it...I also looked at the Django doc...https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
And I just can't see what I might be doing wrong.  Thanks in advance for any help to get me back on track.

Comment: Interesting issue, did you figure it out? Here are some general questions, that might or might not help with your issue: Do you have `app_name = "AppA"` in your AppA.url? Did you update AppA.url to have the correct format already? Is AppA in your installed apps? Are all file names correct? Sorry that these might be very basic, but these are what's the hardest to find for me.

Comment: @Bloodmallet  Thank you for the questions.  And you were correct, I was missing the app_name = "AppA" in my AppA.url file.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me think this through.

Answer (score 2):

As Bloodmallet pointed out to me...

I needed to add....

```
app_name = 'Appa'
```

to the top of my urls.py file.  After doing this, the path URL worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `path()`, consider using [re_path()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path):

```
from django.urls import include, re_path

re_path(r'^Main/',include('AppA.urls',namespace="AppA")),
```